# High Spool Issue

Tags: query-optimization, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

When I run this Update SQL statement it causes a load on the system query taking a High Spool of 2.5TB. PJI is also high, I have already collected stats on it.

```
UPDATE  PMP_CBS.RPT_BILLING_DETAIL_FINAL
    FROM
(
    SEL ACCT_ID,
        Media_type_cd
        FROM PMP_VEW_CBS.RPT_BILLING_DETAIL_FINAL A LEFT JOIN PMP_AVEW.FCT_SUBS_ACCT  B  -- PMP_AVEW.FCT_SUBS_ACCT .. This DB and Table doesnt exist
ON CAST(A.ACCT_ID AS VARCHAR(50))=CAST(B.BILLING_ACCT_ID AS VARCHAR(50))
        WHERE BILLING_MONTH = ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY
        FROM CURRENT_DATE), 0 )(FORMAT 'YYYYMM')(CHAR(06))
            AND  Media_type_cd IS NOT NULL
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCT_ID
        ORDER BY ACCT_ID)=1
        GROUP BY 1,
            2
) A
SET Media_type =A.Media_type_cd
    WHERE PMP_VEW_CBS.RPT_BILLING_DETAIL_FINAL.ACCT_ID=A.ACCT_ID
        AND  PMP_VEW_CBS.RPT_BILLING_DETAIL_FINAL.BILLING_MONTH = ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY
    FROM CURRENT_DATE), 0 )(FORMAT 'YYYYMM')(CHAR(06));
```

Comment: Please don't tag database brands that you're not using. Multi-table UPDATE is not standard SQL, so each brand implements the syntax differently. Your example may work in Teradata, but in MySQL it's a syntax error. So I've edited the question to remove the mysql tag.

Comment: I can't read that code. The indenting and general layout is horrendous. The first step in improving your code, should be improving its legibility, not its performance...

Comment: Why are you casting those ACCT_IDs a VarChars? And PMP_VEW_CBS.RPT_BILLING_DETAIL_FINAL should not be used in the WHERE, it's PMP_CBS.RPT_BILLING_DETAIL_FINAL. Check Explain, there's a `product join where (1=1)`. And what are you actually trying to do, the update is very strange?

Comment: @MatBailie 
We are doing casting because the ACCT_ID data type in the CBS system is BIGINT, however in SEIBEL System, it is VARCHAR. these two systems have different datatypes for the same attribute, I am only upgrading CBS System and the V6 schema of CBS has BIGINT data type for this attribute. As per the project scope, I cannot change the table structure or grain, Hence casting is a must.

Comment: @dnoeth

I don’t see that. We are basically trying to update the media type value for the current month from the Siebel table against acct_ids.

Comment: The first time you are referring to ` PMP_VEW_CBS.RPT_BILLING_DETAIL_FINAL` in the scope of your outer query is in your where clause.  In Teradata, this is a guaranteed product join.   PMP_VEW_CBS. <> PMP_CBS.